# jwtGenerator - invalid input syntax for type uuid: "{}"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, jwt, authorization

i am trying to create login register page with using PERN Stack and jwt

i have a database(vetmed) which consist of

```
CREATE TABLE  veterinaryInfo(   
vetId uuid PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 
uuid_generate_v4(), 
vetName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   
vetSurname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,    
branch_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,   
address VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL , 
email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
phone VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL, 
password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);
```

Here is my jwt.Auth.js code:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const pool = require('../db');
const validInfo = require('../middleware/validInfo');
const jwtGenerator = require('../utils/jwtGenerator');
const authorization = require('../middleware/authorization');

//authorizeentication

router.post('/register', validInfo, async (req, res) => {
 try {
 //1. destructure the req.body ( )
   const { name, surname, branch, address_, mail, phone_, password_ } =
     req.body;

// 2. check if user exist ( if exist then throw error)
const user = await pool.query(
  'SELECT * FROM veterinaryInfo WHERE email = $1',
  [mail]
);
//res.json(user.rows);

if (user.rows.length !== 0) {
  // user already exist
  return res.status(401).send('user already exist');
}

// 3. Bcrypty the user password

const saltRound = 10;
const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(saltRound);

const bcryptPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password_, salt);

// 4. enter the new user inside the database

let newUser = await pool.query(
  'INSERT INTO veterinaryInfo(vetName, vetSurname, branch_Name,address,email,phone,password) VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7) RETURNING *',
  [name, surname, branch, address_, mail, phone_, bcryptPassword]
);

//res.json(newUser.rows[0]);

// 5 generating our jwt token
const token = jwtGenerator(newUser.rows[0].vetId);
res.json({ token });
} catch (err) {
console.error(err.message);
res.status(500).send('server error');
}
});

//login route
router.post('/login', validInfo, async (req, res) => {
try {
// 1. destructure the req.body
const { name, surname, branch, address_, mail, phone_, password_ } =
  req.body;

// 2. check if user doesn't exist (if not then throw error)
const user = await pool.query(
  'SELECT * FROM veterinaryInfo WHERE email = $1',
  [mail]
);

if (user.rows.length === 0) {
  return res.status(401).json('Password or Email is incorrect');
}

// 3. check if incoming password is the same the database password

const validPassword = await bcrypt.compare(
  password_,
  user.rows[0].password
);

// console.log(validPassword);

if (!validPassword) {
  return res.status(401).json('Password or Email is incorrect');
}

// 4. give them the twt token
const token = jwtGenerator(user.rows[0].vetId);
return res.json({ token });
} catch (err) {
console.error(err.message);
res.status(500).send('Server error');
}
});

router.get('/is-verify', authorization, async (req, res) => {
try {
res.json(true);
} catch (err) {
console.error(err.message);
res.status(500).send('server error');
}
});


module.exports = router;
```

In postman i can create a new register successfully, i can use login and is-verify method succesfully. However,

Here is my dashboard.js code :

```
  const router = require('express').Router();
  const authorization = require('../middleware/authorization');
  const pool = require('../db');

  router.get('/', authorization, async (req, res) => {
  try {
  const user = await pool.query(
  'SELECT * FROM veterinaryInfo WHERE vetId = $1',
  [req.user]
  );

  //res.json(user.rows[0]);
  // res.json('hello');
  res.json(user.rows[0]);
  } catch (err) {
  console.error(err.message);
  res.status(500).send('Server error');
  }
  });

  module.exports = router;
```

In postman with http://localhost:5000/dashboard/ when i write the token value on the header which relative to login and is-verify. i can not access the vetId from res.json(user.rows[0])

Here is my jwtGenerator.js code:

```
  const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
  require('dotenv').config();
 //Look at file server/routes/dashboard.js to see the change code for this code

 function jwtGenerator(vetId) {
 const payload = {
 user: vetId,
 };
/*function jwtGenerator(vetId) {
 const payload = {
 user: {
  id: vetId,
 },
};*/

 return jwt.sign(payload, process.env.jwtSecret, { expiresIn: '1h' });
 }

 module.exports = jwtGenerator;
```

authorization.js code :

```
 const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
 require('dotenv').config();

 //this middleware will on continue on if the token is inside the local storage

 module.exports = async (req, res, next) => {
 try {
 // Get token from header
 const jwtToken = req.header('token');

 // Check if not token
 if (!jwtToken) {
   return res.status(403).json('not authorize');
 }

 // Verify token

 //it is going to give use the user id (user:{id: user.id})
 const payload = jwt.verify(jwtToken, process.env.jwtSecret);
 //console.log(jwtToken);
 req.user = payload.user;
 console.log(req.user);
 next();
 }catch (err) {
 console.error(err.message);
 res.status(403).json('not authorize');
 }
 };
```

index.js code :

```
 const express = require('express');
 const app = express();
 const cors = require('cors');

 app.use(express.json()); // req body
 app.use(cors());

 //ROUTES

 //register and login routes
 app.use('/auth', require('./routes/jwtAuth')); // activate routes
 app.use('/dashboard', require('./routes/dashboard')); // dashboard route

 app.listen(5000, () => {
 console.log('server is running on port 5000');
 });
```

the output is

```
 [nodemon] restarting due to changes...
 [nodemon] starting `node index index.js`
 server is running on port 5000
 {}
 invalid input syntax for type uuid: "{}"
```

Comment: Please post also your index.js